# How to pass the data from "Examples" Section to Step Definition in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I Have a Scenario and need to execute the same scenario in three different environment. So I have used Scenario Outline and it looks like below.

Scenario Outline: Create Test Success flow

```
Given Login to AAA Application in "<Environment>"

When  Enter the Customer Details

Then  Select the Service
```

Examples: |Environment|

```
|QA|
|UAT|
|Prod|
```

So my question here is how to achieve this in step definition. I don't want to hardcode the data in feature file. So if Environment is QA then QA data should pass, Same like UAT means UAT data should automatically fetch..

Step definition:
@Given("^Login to AAA Application in "([^"]*)"$")

```
public void Login_to_AAA_Application(String Environment) throws Throwable
```

{

// How to write code here for all the environment. And My scenario need to execute based on the environment provided in Examples section of Scenario outline.

}

Any suggestion/help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you can use the switch case to assign a value to global variable in each case.

Comment: This is not something you would do in a scenario/example, but in the configuration of running your tests. How to do that depends on your tech stack.

Comment: @DilipMeghwal - If possible can you please elaborate. I did same thing but it is not working.               For Ex: switch(Environment){ case "INT": break; case "UAT": break;}

Comment: @Marit - Need More Clarity.. My question is simple.. I Want to execute same scenario with different environment without hard code the data in Examples section.

Answer (score 0):

Create property files(eg. QA.properties) for each env which contains data like `url`, `credentials` etc.

Sample QA.properties file content.

```
browser=chrome
testSiteUrl=https://parabank.parasoft.com/parabank/index.htm
```

Step definition code.

```
public  Properties QaPropFile = new Properties();
public  Properties ProdPropFile = new Properties();
public  Properties UATPropFile = new Properties();

public void Login_to_AAA_Application(String Environment) throws Throwable{
    switch(Environment) {
        case "QA":
            FileInputStream QaFileobj = new FileInputStream("filePath");
            QaPropFile.load(QaFileobj);
            break;
        case "Prod":
            FileInputStream ProdFileobj = new FileInputStream("filePath");
            ProdPropFile.load(ProdFileobj);
            break;
        case "UAT":
            FileInputStream UatFileobj = new FileInputStream("filePath");
            UATPropFile.load(UatFileobj);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println(Environment + " is not a valid envieonment");
    }
}
```

And when you want to access this try below code.

```
QaPropFile.get("testSiteUrl");
```